# bootstrap one row contain two col. one contain image and other background image

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

We are using bootstrap, when I take a row and divide it into two column(col-*-6 and col-*-6), then one column contains the responsive image having img-responsive class and other col contains the description of the image having background color/image. but this color/image size is not equal to first column having image when I viewed it on mobile screen. Here is my code:

```css
.myfontpage{ background:URL(Image/main.jpg) center no-repeat; width:100%; height:100%; }

.myfontpage h1,p{padding:15px 30px;  text-align:center; font-size:4vw;}
```

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="container">
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <img src="Image/main.jpg" alt="Can not Display" class="imp-responsive"/>
        </div>
     
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 myfontpage">
          <h1>Welcome to Yoga fitness club</h1>
   <p>This is free template. only for the practices </a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the complete code of your html file?

Answer (score 1):

As much I have understood your question, I think you need both the columns of same size.
try removing width:100%; height:100%;  from 'myfontpage' class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not included the js and css files for bootstrap.
You can include it in your project by downloading it or using the following CDN:

For CSS:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

For JS:

```
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```